# Having trouble with struct pointers

Tags: c, pointers, netbeans, struct

I'm having trouble while trying to compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct Aposta{
   char apostador[100];
   char time1[100];
   char time2[100];
   char time3[100];
}Apostas;

typedef struct Jogos{
   char time1[100];
   int gol1;
   char time2[100];
   int gol2;
   int faltas;
   int amarelo;
   int vermelho;    
}Jogo;

typedef struct Times{
   char time[100];
}Time;

typedef struct Tbela{
   char time[100];
   int pontos;
   int ngole;
   int ngols;
}Tabela;

Tabela *ptTabela(Time *time, Jogo *jogo, int tamt, int tamj){
   int i=0;
   Tabela *tabela;
   tabela = (Tabela *)malloc((tamt)*(sizeof(Tabela)));
   while (i < tamt){
      tabela[i].pontos = 0;
      tabela[i].ngole = 0;
      tabela[i].ngols = 0;
      int l;
      for (l=0; l < tamj; l++){
         if(!(strcmp(time[i].time, jogo[l].time1 ))){
            tabela[i].time = jogo[l].time1;
            if(jogo[l].gol1 > jogo[l].gol2){
               tabela[i].pontos = (tabela[i].pontos + 3);
            }
            if(jogo[l].gol1 = jogo[l].gol2){
               tabela[i].pontos = (tabela[i].pontos + 1);
            }
            tabela[i].ngole = tabela[i].ngole + jogo[l].gol1;
            tabela[i].ngols = tabela[i].ngols + jogo[l].gol2;
         }
         else if(!(strcmp(time[i].time, jogo[l].time2 ))){
            tabela[i].time = jogo[l].time2;
            if(jogo[l].gol2 > jogo[l].gol1){
               tabela[i].pontos = (tabela[i].pontos + 3);
            }
            if(jogo[l].gol1 = jogo[l].gol2){
               tabela[i].pontos = (tabela[i].pontos + 1);
            }
            tabela[i].ngole = tabela[i].ngole + jogo[l].gol2;
            tabela[i].ngols = tabela[i].ngols + jogo[l].gol1;
         }
         else{
            printf("Time %s not found.", time[i].time);
         }

      }
   }
   i++;
}
```

The compiler says:
[image]

I really don't know what is wrong with it, for me, it's just supposed to get the string that is inside `jogo[l].time1` and copy it to `tabela[i].time`. And it looks like they are the exact same type.

I'm using netbeans 7.2 .

Thank you for your patience already. If something is not clear, please, let me know and I will correct it as fast as I can.

Comment: You can't just assign an array's contents like that.  Use one of the copy functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do `strdup` or `strcpy` or `strncpy`... - otherwise you make the pointer (which had space allocated to it) point to a new location and that is probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: I thought it was a pointer problem(I had so many of these!), thanks for your direct and clear answer, I forgot that detail about strings.

Comment: We have all done it... it is a good thing that compilers test for these things. Also, I would recommend always to compile with maximum warning level enabled, and keep fixing code until it is "clean". It will save you trouble down the road. Glad you found it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`tabela[i].time = jogo[l].time1;`

`time` is a char array. You are trying to assign a string literal to it which is incorrect. You should use `strcpy` to copy like,

```
strcpy(tabela[i].time, jogo[l].time1);
```